# Application Process Unusable After "... - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers."

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm not sure if I should view this as a bug or just something I need to work around.

I have a Flask application that serves both web requests and kicks off threads for backend jobs. I just had a backend job result in the above failure when connecting to a DB I periodically pull data from. The table it failed to map isn't even one I query in that database, but its failure to map not only resulted in that backend job failing, but it puts SQLAlchemy in a state that it's unable to map ANYTHING else from that point on -- including to serve web requests that don't even access that database!

This was also just a fluke problem. I restarted my application and the table that failed to map mapped just fine.

Is there a way to prevent SQLAlchemy from going into this "WILL NOT MAP!" state in an application? If it were contained to an individual connection it wouldn't be as big a deal but seems to store it in the global space and thus utterly breaks the application from the point of failure, on.

Edit:
It's finally come up again. Here's the full stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmittner/loci2/app/jobs.py", line 506, in start
    result = self.callable(self,**self.parameters)
  File "/home/dmittner/loci2/app/jobs.py", line 467, in job_test
    breakout_property = False
  File "/home/dmittner/loci2/app/api/mod_system/services.py", line 1166, in get_usage
    threshold = summary_threshold
  File "/home/dmittner/loci2/app/api/mod_system/services.py", line 2243, in _get_usage_summary
    'id': result2.regional_region_id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 242, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 598, in get
    value = state._load_expired(state, passive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 608, in _load_expired
    self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 844, in load_scalar_attributes
    session.query(mapper),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1393, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 151, in _set_entities
    self._set_entity_selectables(self._entities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 181, in _set_entity_selectables
    ent.setup_entity(*d[entity])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3619, in setup_entity
    self._with_polymorphic = ext_info.with_polymorphic_mappers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 767, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1994, in _with_polymorphic_mappers
    configure_mappers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3013, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1811, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 184, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1655, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1712, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.mapper.mapped_table
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 767, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1634, in mapper
    configure=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 426, in class_mapper
    raise exc.UnmappedClassError(class_)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.geo_state_map_data' is not mapped
```

It might be worth noting that the geo_state table isn't even a table I use, but one the automapper is dealing with, anyway. And from that point on I get the original message preventing the process from successfully making any new connections.

From looking in SQLAlchemy's code, mappers are stored in a _mapper_registry global space variable and once any mapper in the registry errors out, any attempt to configure a new mapper will fail.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @univerio Unfortunately no. By the time I saw your comment the stack trace was out of my client's buffer. And since it happens as flukes I'm not able to reproduce the specific cause I had before. Though I think *any* mapping failure leads to the same error and the same problem as described above.

Comment: @univerio Trace added to OP

Comment: note _mapper_registry is a WeakKeyDictionary.  Lose the references to the bad mappers and new mappers will configure just fine.